# Join special characters in list elements

Tags: python, string, list

How to join some special characters in a particular element in a list?

eg

```
lst = ['Bhanu','23','08','1989','Hello World']
```

How to add a special character `"/"` in between `23`, `08`, `1989` and make it as `'23/08/1989'` as a single element of a list?

Answer (score 3):

You want to *replace* the middle 3 elements, and use the [`str.join()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to produce the replacement:

```
lst[1:4] = ['/'.join(lst[1:4])]
```

Note that the right-hand-side expression is put into a list object, so you can replace multiple elements in the original list with just the one result.

Demo:

```
>>> lst = ['Bhanu','23','08','1989','Hello World']
>>> '/'.join(lst[1:4])
'23/08/1989'
>>> lst[1:4] = ['/'.join(lst[1:4])]
>>> lst
['Bhanu', '23/08/1989', 'Hello World']
```